# Need simple help to develop c# algorithm

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF. On my window there is a data grid which binding with observable collection. This collection contains data about room check outs. So there is also one window which must add service collection to data grid `>>` create new collection with name of service an fill cell with price.

This price must be set on row where  `id(column) == "example"`. I think it must be very easy but I'm trying this 2 days.. so my question : is it possible to bind data grid with two collections?

How I can add collection new property ? Like that : `public string ServiceName{get;set;}` from another window.

Please advice some good thing how to solve this problem

Comment: Why you need adding ServiceName as property of collection? Why just not to bind it directly to TextBox? BTW, are you using MVVM or your model classes in code behind of a View?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To bind to multiple collections use the CompositeCollection.

Here's a ListBox example:

```
<ListBox Name="myListBox" Height="300" Width="200" Background="White">
  <ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <CollectionContainer
        Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GreekGodsData}}" />
      <CollectionContainer
        Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GreekHeroesData}}" />
      <ListBoxItem Foreground="Red">Other Listbox Item 1</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem Foreground="Red">Other Listbox Item 2</ListBoxItem>
    </CompositeCollection>
  </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

This example and more info can be found on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx.

Another important point to mention is CompositeCollection **does not implement IEditableCollectionView** so if you need to edit the datagrid, you cannot use CompositeCollection without implementing IEditableCollectionView yourself.

Comment: Never knew either! WPF surprises me!

Comment: wow its good but my try was unsuccessful. When i bind collection from code behind grids shows only second coll. this is xaml : <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source=CheckOutCollection}"/>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source=ServiceCollection}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </DataGrid.ItemsSource>

Comment: Hmmm...Will you please update your question with the class(es) stored in your collections?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't bind a property to two things at the same time.
Normaly you would aggregate the two data-objects into a single Helperobject and use those in the observable-collection.

Comment: You can use the CompositeCollection to bind.  I just found this out a month ago while trying to build a collection for a menu.  See my answer above.

Comment: ok thanks - I guess I have to do more "know your framework" ;)

Comment: Good luck with that and WPF.  I swear I see something new everyday.

Comment: true - hard to stay on top as a "you do everything guy"